# Measuring just half the sine wave of a current measuring transformer?

Tags: adc, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, current-transformer

I'd like to measure current of electrical devices using one of those split-core transformers you clip around an AC wire, which has a built in shunt resistor and hence outputs a voltage.
I'd like to to this with minimal components.

All the tutorials online add a DC bias to shift the wave up a bit, and then run it through a ADC.

Could I get away without adding the relatively complex DC bias?
If I just measure the amplitude of the positive side of the sine wave and multiply it by two (and cut off the negative side in case the ADC doesn't like negative voltage, I guess), shouldn't I get the exact same measurement?

Or would it make a difference to simply rectify the incoming sine wave and measure that wave's amplitude?

What is the benefit of the DC bias?

Comment: You have to consider the voltage drop of your rectifier. What are you going to do with the current measurement? Are you taking multiple samples per half-cycle?

Comment: The problem with cutting off the bottom half is, how do you determine if you have 0 current vs being in the negative half cycle?  It's solvable, but gets tricky.

Comment: 2 bias resistors seems simpler than a rectifier. Many single-ended ADC inputs are protected with internal clamping diodes, which would disrupt an unbiased input from the current transformer.

Comment: The idea is to feed it into an Arduino/ESP8266 via the ADC pins,to measure current consumption.


I guess id have to take the maximum voltage of many readings over a certain time frame (e.g. one second) to 'catch' the maximum - which AFAIK is the only way to measure a sine wave's amplitude with an ADC


I'd prefer not to use a rectifier - maybe just 'dump' the reverse voltage to a resistor via a diode (if the ADC can't resist negative voltage), and measure the positive part with the ADC.

Comment: @MoritzvonSchweinitz Probably the simplest technique (and least expensive) that will add just the right DC bias is in fact to use a capacitor. I may write an article, but I already found one (since I knew what to look for.) The basic idea is [illustrated here](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/sites/default/files/Arduino%20AC%20current%20input%20A.png) and the article is [here](https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/156.html). If someone wants me to write an answer on this, with elaboration, I'll be happy to do it (to capture the answer on this site.) Meantime, read those.

Comment: @MoritzvonSchweinitz By the way, selection of the current transformer (or its design for the purpose) is important. You can't just slap any old CT on and then fix things up afterwards. You want to match impedances as well as possible, for example. And this means considering your input signal (the magnetic field itself), your transducer (the CT), your chosen load resistor, virtual ground setup, and the ADC input impedance in order to get the most from the system.

Comment: @jonk A quick summary with pictures is probably best, in case that link goes away.

Comment: @Aaron If so, it will have to wait as I have a priority request from a client and calendar time is the critical boundary condition on it. I have time for "comments" when I sip coffee. But no more than that, at least for today.

Comment: If the ADC has differential inputs and the current transformer output is isolated, it may be possible to directly measure positive and negative voltages, as long as the signal voltage range matches one of the ADC. I have no experience with floating ADC inputs though, not sure there are no hidden issues.

Comment: @MoritzvonSchweinitz Can you identify the CT you are considering? Or what's the range of current? Also, consider [EESE answer on current transformer design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136086/how-do-i-design-a-current-transformer).

Comment: @jonk i'm just planning to use the standard readily available ones with a built-in burden resistor like e.g. the SCT-013-015. On my cheap 'scope, it shows a pretty voltage up to 1V, .
And my basic question still stands - why not simply measure the positive half-wave's peak with an ADC and calculate the current based on that? Why go through the whole DC bias and capacitor or rectifying route?